# Repaint a Paintbox does not work

Tags: delphi

My function to paint an Image into a paintbox is called from to 2 locations, If called from a TPagecontrol pagechange  it  works fine, but if called from a form.formresize(….)  the image is painted but immediately afterwards  the paintbox is repainted an getting completely white.  Do not have any idea from what sequence this malefinction comes from ---

```
procedure TForm.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
     //  frist image shown and then re painted white ???
     PaintImage2PaintBox(……….);
end;  


procedure TForm.pgc_mainmenuChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
     //  works fine as  expected  after pagecontrol  tab change 

      PaintImage2PaintBox(……….);
end;;

procedure PaintImage2PaintBox(……….);
begin
        ///  draw into a PaintBox
end;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't call the paint box `OnPaint` event handler yourself. When you do so the paint box canvas is not properly prepared. In order to force the paint box to repaint you need to call the `Invalidate` or `Repaint` methods. Like this:

```
PaintBox1.Invalidate;
```

or

```
PaintBox1.Repaint;
```

Calling `Invalidate` results in asynchronous repainting. The control is marked as being *dirty* and when the message queue is next empty a `WM_PAINT` message is synthesised and the control will be repainted.

Calling `Repaint` forces a synchronous paint cycle. That is, the paint will be performed, and then the `Repaint` function will return.

Unless you have a special reason for forcing synchronous re-paint, I suggest that you call `Invalidate`.

@Sertac suggests in a comment that your painting code is not in an `OnPaint` handler. If that is so then that is an even bigger problem. You must put all your painting code in the event handler attached to the paint box `OnPaint` event.